# Trying to understand how to bulk update via a schedule trigger flow

Tags: visual-workflow, loop, bulkification

I created a schedule trigger flow to update 1000s of opportunities every night.  The job of this flow is to find any inactive opportunity and close-lose it.  However, I am hitting "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW" errors, because there are multiple opportunities I am trying to close-lose that are associated with the same Account.  Since a schedule flow by design updates 1 record at a time, I believe that is why I am hitting this error.  If I can bulk update a set of records, I believe I will solve this issue.  I saw one post on how to do it, but he was making an update within a Loop and I know that is bad practice.

Any guidance?

Comment: Schedule-triggered flows are bulkified - however many records SFDC decides to present (200, see [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdccSUAR/scheduled-flow-batch-size-option)) in a transaction will each get their own Flow Interview and all flow interviews in that transaction will be [bulkifed as per the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5).  You may have competing other automation going on